# Repeat a macro in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to select a random sample of 6 cases from a dataset (test2) below.  The cases have to be selected in a specific order ED,CCM,MAT,CAC. The first pass will be from payer 1 (P1) and the second pass from payer 2 (P2) until I get a total of 6 cases. Within each measure type, the case with the lowest random number gets selected first. Below is the macro I am using which I want to be able to repeat by payers.

```
ID  Measure Payer
1439  CAC  P1
1135  CCM  P1
1736  ED   P1
1737  MAT  P1
1738  CCM  P2
2351  ED   P2
4251  ED   P1


DATA CAC CCM ED MAT;
set test2;
    if measure = 'CAC' then output CAC;
else if measure = 'CCM'  then output CCM;
else if measure = 'ED' then output ED;
else if measure = 'MAT' then output MAT;
RUN;


%MACRO select (dsn,num);

DATA &dsn;
  set &dsn;

  min_random=min(random);
RUN;
PROC SORT data=&dsn;
  by Payer min_random;
RUN;
DATA &dsn;
   set &dsn;
   if _N_ le &num;
RUN;

 %MEND select;

%SELECT(ED,1);  %SELECT(CCM,1);  %SELECT(MAT,1); %SELECT(CAC,1); 

DATA sample1A;
set ED CCM MAT CAC;
RUN;
```

For the sample dataset above the output of 6 cases should be

```
1736  ED   P1
1135  CCM  P1
1737  MAT  P1
1439  CAC  P1
2351  ED   P2
1738  CCM  P2
```

Comment: What is PMT_SRC_GROUP?

Comment: Have you executed your code?  min_random=min(random); this does not work, I will put another random function here

Comment: I hope you understand that since you are using the random numbers, so you might not get the same output that you have posted up here, there may be two 1736 EDs or 1135 CCMs!!, only the order of ED, CCM, MAT, CAC is fixed.

Comment: I did execute my code and the min(random)works. I do understand that since I am using random numbers depending on the seed, the results will vary. But I need to choose the record with a measure (category) with the lowest random number first and need to repeat the process through payers to get a total of 6 random cases. All odd passes are for Payer 1 and even passes for Payer 2.

Comment: I have not modified your logic.See below

Comment: Thanks NEOmen. The sample dataset I get now doesnot have any records from Payer P2. First pass is from P1 and second pass from P2 is what my logic says. I get the same record for ED and CCM selected twice id 1736, 1135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I achieved it..

```
data test2;set test2;
ran=ranuni(123);
if measure='ED' then order=1;
if measure='CCM' then order=2;
if measure='MAT' then order=3;
if measure='CAC' then order=4;
run;

proc sort data= test2 out=P1;
by order payer ran;
where payer='P1';
run;

proc sort data= test2 out=P2;
by order payer ran;
where payer='P2';
run;

data S1 S3;set P1;
by order ran;
if first.order then output S1;else
output S3;
run;

data S2 S4;set P2;
by order ran;
if first.order then output S2;else
output S4;
run;

data sample;
set S1 S2 S3 S4;
run;

data sample;set sample (obs=6);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve this problem in the following way:

1. Counting the number of full loops required to get the number of records. Each loop will fetch 4 records ( each for ED,CCM,MAT,CAC). In your case it would be 1.
2. Counting the number of half loops required to get the number of records. In your case, it would be two - each for ED and CCM.

Below is the code, which is pretty much self explanatory.

---

Creating the sample dataset

```
data test2;
infile datalines;
input ID Measure $ Payer $;
datalines;
1439  CAC  P1
1135  CCM  P1
1736  ED   P1
1737  MAT  P1
1738  CCM  P2
2351  ED   P2
4251  ED   P1
;
run;


DATA CAC CCM ED MAT;
set test2;
    if measure = 'CAC' then output CAC;
else if measure = 'CCM'  then output CCM;
else if measure = 'ED' then output ED;
else if measure = 'MAT' then output MAT;
RUN;


%MACRO select (dsn,num);

DATA &dsn;
  set &dsn;

  min_random=ranuni(0);
RUN;
PROC SORT data=&dsn;
  by Payer min_random;
RUN;
DATA &dsn;
   set &dsn;
   if _N_ le &num;
RUN;

proc append base=sample1A data=&dsn. force;
run;

%MEND select;

%macro loop;

%let inp=ED,CCM,MAT,CAC;
%let Num_of_records_to_extract=6;
%let Num_of_distinct_measure=4;

data _NULL_;
loop_count=int(&Num_of_records_to_extract./&Num_of_distinct_measure.);
semi_loop_count=mod(&Num_of_records_to_extract.,&Num_of_distinct_measure.);
call symputx("loop_count",loop_count);
call symputx("semi_loop_count",semi_loop_count);
run;

%if &loop_count. ge 1 %then %do;
   %do i=1 %to &loop_count.; 
       %do j=1 %to 4;
          %SELECT(%sysfunc(scan("&inp.",&j.,",")),1);  
        %end;
    %end;
%end;

%if &semi_loop_count. ge 1 %then %do;
       %do k=1 %to &semi_loop_count.;
          %SELECT(%sysfunc(scan("&inp.",&k.,",")),1);  
        %end;
%end;


%mend;
%loop;
```

Comment: The same case cannot be repeated in the sample

Answer (score 0):

There are less busy ways. Anytime you can use by-group processing instead of macro-loops, you should. And in this case there's no need to break the dataset in lots of parts to do this, that's expensive in terms of I/O if the dataset is large.

This is a easy maintenance solution ... not tested:

```
    %let SAMPLE_SIZE=6 ;

    proc format ; 
       value $measure2order
        'ED'  = '1'
        'CCM' = '2'
        'MAT' = '3'
        'CAC' = '4'
        other = 'X'
           ; run;

    *--- changing dataset name because I am tossing  ---* ;
    *---    records with unexpected values (or more  ---* ;
    *---    specifically, measures that are not      ---* ;
    *---    needed for this particular sample.)      ---* ;
    data SAMPLE 
         ODD_STUFF ;
    set test2 ;
       random=ranuni(123) ;
       order=put(measure,$measure2order.) ;
       if order='X' then output ODD_STUFF ;
       else output SAMPLE ;
       run; 

       proc sort data=SAMPLE ;
          by payer order random ;
          run;

          data SAMPLE ;
          set SAMPLE ;
          by payer order random ;
             if first.order ;
             sample_count+1 ;
             output ;
             if sample_count GE &SAMPLE_SIZE then stop ; 
             drop random sample_count ;
             run;
```

(Note in passing ... the problem definition here seems wacky. Assuming you have a good set of data, your sample will have 1 random record for each of the four measures for payer=1, and 1 random record for each of the first 2 measures for payer=2.)